# Countif for unique combinations in Excel

Tags: excel, count

So I have this list of contract connected to different vehicles covering different job types. I want to count how many vehicles are in a contract like shown in the table next to **desired solution.** I thought something with concatenate would work, but I have no clue how.

[image: Example Data Set]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is...

First extract unique item from column A. Use below formula to do that.As per below screenshot put this formula to `E2` cell normally.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$9,MATCH(0,INDEX(COUNTIF($E$1:E1,$A$2:$A$9),0,0),0)),"")
```

In `F2` cell enter below formula as an array formula to count vehicle based on condition from `Column A`.

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF($A$2:$A$9=E2,IF($B$2:$B$9<>"",MATCH("~"&$B$2:$B$9,$B$2:$B$9&"",0))),ROW($B$2:$B$9)-ROW($B$2)+1),1))
```

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to evaluate the formula as it is an array formula.

***Screenshot:***

[image]

Comment: The dataset I'm applying this to is confidential so I can't share it. It contains more data than the example sheet, so it shows "0" as an answer and keeps showing the "calculating (4 threads)" status. Can this formula be applied to a big(ger) dataset without causing too much trouble?

Comment: Array formula always slow. Set,  vba macro will faster in this case.

Answer (score 1):

For counting amount of vehicles you can use conventional formula (according to Harun24HR's example in F2 cell):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--($A$2:$A$9=E2)*(1/COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$9,$A$2:$A$9,$B$2:$B$9,$B$2:$B$9)))
```

Comment: Upvote for you. I like `conventional` formula as it is always faster than `Array` formula.